# нужно проверить большой файл .csv и заменить, и классифицировать в нем один столбец

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Хола, мне нужно проверить большой файл .csv и заменить, и проклассифицировать в нем один столбец dataframe['value']. Вот мои код, но он работает медленно. Есть ли более лучшее решение?

Это мой код но он работает медленно:

```
def encoder():
    classes={}
    a=dataframe['value']
    c=-1
    for i in a:
        if i not in classes:
            print(i)
            c=c+1
            classes[i]=c
    for i in range(len(a)):
        print(i)
        dataframe['value'][i]=classes[a[i]]
```

Есть ли более лучше оптимизированное решение? которое работает быстрее?

Вот часть данных:

```
subject_id  hadm_id seq_num icd9_code   icustay_id  value   valueuom
    18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
    18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
    18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
    18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    Tracheostomy    0
    18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    30  0
    18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    30  0
    18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    30  0
    18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    30  0
    18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
    18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
    18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
    18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    2 Person Assist 0
    18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    Calm    0
    18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    Calm    0
    18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    Calm    0
    18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    Calm    0
    18557   183341  4   42731   228376.0    Present 0
    18557   178725  4   42731   228376.0    Present 0
    18557   173656  5   42731   228376.0    Present 0
    18557   138883  10  42731   228376.0    Present 0
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы подробнее описать, что нужно сделать со значением? Уверен, ваш код можно сделать быстрее, поскольку вы вообще не используете встроенные методы pandas, и датафрейм у вас просто хранилище данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример исходного DataFrame:

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]:
  name  val
0  xxx    9
1  aaa   11
2  bbb   12
3  aaa   15
4  ccc   10
5  yyy   15
6  bbb   19
```

для того, чтобы закодировать строковые значения в числовые (0, 1, 2, ..., N) можно воспользоваться одним из следующих методом:

**[categorical dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html):**

```
In [73]: df["name"] = df["name"].astype("category")

In [74]: df
Out[74]:
  name  val
0  xxx    9
1  aaa   11
2  bbb   12
3  aaa   15
4  ccc   10
5  yyy   15
6  bbb   19

In [75]: df.dtypes
Out[75]:
name    category
val        int64
dtype: object

In [76]: df["name"].cat.categories
Out[76]: Index(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xxx', 'yyy'], dtype='object')
```

чтобы использовать закодированные числовые значения можно воспользоваться атрибутом `Series.cat.codes`:

```
In [77]: df["name"].cat.codes
Out[77]:
0    3
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    2
5    4
6    1
dtype: int8
```

---

[**pd.factorize()**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
In [79]: codes, cats = pd.factorize(df["name"])

In [80]: codes
Out[80]: array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2], dtype=int64)

In [81]: cats
Out[81]: Index(['xxx', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'yyy'], dtype='object')

In [82]: codes, cats = pd.factorize(df["name"], sort=True)

In [83]: cats
Out[83]: Index(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xxx', 'yyy'], dtype='object')

In [84]: codes
Out[84]: array([3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

---

[**sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder):

```
In [89]: from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

In [90]: oe = OrdinalEncoder(dtype="int")

In [91]: df["name_encoded"] = oe.fit_transform(df[["name"]])

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
  name  val  name_encoded
0  xxx    9             3
1  aaa   11             0
2  bbb   12             1
3  aaa   15             0
4  ccc   10             2
5  yyy   15             4
6  bbb   19             1
```

Comment: а если хочется превратить содержимое столбца в значения специализированного типа pandas - забыл как он там называется. что то типа наборов.. ((
.
Ну чтоб результат соответствовал тому коду, что привел автор?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, дополнил ответ)